# Hide all Xprofile fields from buddypress registration page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to remove the all the xprofile field group from register page and show them only to edit profile page.
I have tried to remove the section that was displaying the xprofile fields group(Primary) from register.php file by copying that to my theme folder but it is restricting me from registering the user.
Anyone here has any solution?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit this page on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.  “buddypress” contains template files; copy any you want to modify into a directory named “buddypress” in your theme’s root. eg. /wp-content/mytheme/buddypress/. So if you go  /wp-content/mytheme/buddypress/members/. You will see register.php which you can edit. 
you can either delete or remove xprofile fields in register.php page.

```
<?php while ( bp_profile_fields() ) : bp_the_profile_field(); ?>
```

Comment: No, It will display error if Name field is not added in the register Process.
But I have managed to accomplish this using My custom code. I have auto populated the Name field by using some jquery.
Thanks.